# What's going on in the word 同い年?

Tags: etymology

The word 同い年 is presumably related to the adjective 同じ. But what happened to the consonant in the root? I thought this might be an example of イ音便, but typically this happens to -k, -g only.

Is this odd change idiosyncratic to this word? Or does 同じ decompose further into ona-j-i such that there is some other root ona-?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a look at the 日本国語大辞典【にほんこくごだいじてん】 (NKD) [entry](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E5%90%8C%E5%B9%B4-581142).  The NKD is a bit like the Oxford English, it's one of the better dictionaries for giving word derivations.

According to the entry, this reading *onaidoshi* is an irregular sound shift from older *onajitoshi*.  The *onaidoshi* version first shows up in 1563.

Phonologically, it looks like the voicing on the じ influenced the と to voice to ど.  And with the じ and the ど both starting with front-of-the-mouth consonants, I can see how the consonant in じ would elide (become omitted).

→ At any rate, consider this particular word as a kind of one-off: memorize it, but don't view this as indicative of any common pattern where ～じ becomes ～い.

Comment: FYI: http://ichhan.sakura.ne.jp/rendaku/rendaku22.html